# Why are Shortcodes Disabled in Widgets by Default?

Tags: shortcode, widgets, customization

I've looked all around but can't seem to locate a definitive answer for my question: why are WordPress shortcodes disabled by default in text widgets?

It's super easy to enable them, with the line `add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode')`, so I'm just curious as to why WordPress doesn't have that option enabled by default.

Is it for potential security reasons? Page rendering speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has been the case for a long time, text widget existed before shortcodes were added to WordPress, and since then, no one bothered to implement it. But, version 4.9 scheduled for November/December will finally have this enabled for the text widget.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is actually very simple, the text widget is not a full blown content and many shortcodes need the context of a content (or more correctly, post) to execute properly.

As @milan said, in 4.9 this is going to change from a technical point of view, but many shortcodes are unlikely to work which is not a great user experience.

Comment: Yeah, the widgets that were written to work with the current post will not work, and some might cause problems when used in the widget. Shortcodes that are not post specific will work fine.